# Extract substring in python if pattern exists

Tags: python, regex, python-re

How can I replace a string with a matched group *if* it exists?

```
text1 = "some text (ID: 1234) some text some text"  # --> 1234
text2 = "some text (ID: abc) some (text) some text" # --> abc 
text3 = "some text some text some text some text"   # --> some text some text some text some text
texts = pd.Series([text1, text2, text3])
```

I know the regex function to replace the texts with the ID using a lambda function *if and only if* it matches. The re pattern to identify it would be `'.*\(ID:\s(.*)\).*'`, where the group (.*) is the ID I need.

`re.sub` only seems to substitute entire matched portions, and re.search

```
texts = texts.apply(lambda x: SOME_REGEX)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the pattern provided: `'.*\(ID:\s(.*)\).*'` there is a single *group*, `(.*)`. A group is a pattern that is enclosed in parenthesis. As this is the first group in the pattern, you can reference it as `'\1'` in `re.sub`.

For the problem you asked:

```
|-------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------|
|          texts                            |               cleaned                   |
|-------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------|
|"some text (ID: 1234) some text some text" |                1234                     |
|"some text (ID: abc) some (text) some text"|                abc                      |
|"some text some text some text some text"  |"some text some text some text some text"|
|-------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------|
```

The following code will work:

```
pattern = `'.*\(ID:\s(.*)\).*'`
cleaned = texts.apply(lambda x: re.sub(pattern, r'\1', flag=IGNORECASE))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should either make the `.*` part non greedy using `.*?` or use a negated character class matching any char except parenthesis `[^()]+` or else you will not have just `abc` in group 1.

There should be no backticks around the pattern, and the property name is `flags` instead of flag setting a value or `re.IGNORECASE`

```
import re
import pandas as pd

text1 = "some text (ID: 1234) some text some text"  # --> 1234
text2 = "some text (ID: abc) some (text) some text" # --> abc 
text3 = "some text some text some text some text"   # --> some text some text some text some text
texts = pd.Series([text1, text2, text3])

pattern = '.*\(ID:\s([^()]+)\).*'
cleaned = texts.apply(lambda x: re.sub(pattern, r'\1', x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
print(cleaned)
```

Output

```
0                                       1234
1                                        abc
2    some text some text some text some text
```